# How to update worksheet from VBA dictionary without performance issues?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a rather large spreadsheet (sheet A) (400k rows), all with a unique identifier.

I have ~150k of these in another spreadsheet (sheet B), which needs to transfer its values. To do this, I store each ID in a dictionary and its values to update in an array in its value. E.g.

```
dict.Add 'ID_01', Array('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
```

Then to update, I run through sheet A and whenever that ID is encountered, it updates the cells. For a rough idea:

```
With sheet A
For i = 2 to lastrow:
    If dict.exists(.Cells(i, 1).value) Then
        .Cells(i, 2).Value = dict.Item(.Cells(i,1).Value)(0)
        .Cells(i, 3).Value = dict.Item(.Cells(i,1).Value)(1)
        .Cells(i, 4).Value = dict.Item(.Cells(i,1).Value)(2)
Next i
```

End With

The above is only a mock example, but you can see why this can take a long time, often above 10 minutes. The bottleneck is not adding the IDs/values to the dictionary from Sheet B, but rather updating them back in Sheet A.

My question is: Is there a way for me to update these values much more quickly while still retaining my dictionary structure?

Any help is appreciated, but it'd be preferable if any proposed solutions didn't stray too far from the general approach I have outlined above.

Comment: Write the `Dictionary` to an intermediary 2D array, then transfer it to the sheet in a single `Range.Value` call. Reads and writes to the worksheet are expensive.

Comment: @Comintern I'm not sure I understand how this would work. How would the IDs be matched correctly?

Comment: Look them up from a second array. Everything is sequential so [it shouldn't be horribly difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54586126/4088852).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create and populate a 2-D array in memory then dump the array back to the worksheet.

```
'at this point the dictionary is already populated similar to
'dict.Add 'ID_01', Array('val1', 'val2', 'val3')

dim i as long, arr as variant

with sheet a

    arr = .range(.cells(2, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup)).value2
    redim preserve arr(lbound(arr, 1) to ubound(arr, 1), 1 to 4)
    'if sheet A already has values that only require updating,
    'then use this instead
    'arr = .range(.cells(2, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).offset(0, 3)).value2

    for i=lbound(arr, 1) to ubound(arr, 1)
        If dict.exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            arr(i, 2) = dict.Item(arr(i, 1))(0)
            arr(i, 3) = dict.Item(arr(i, 1))(1)
            arr(i, 4) = dict.Item(arr(i, 1))(2)
        end if
    next i

    .cells(2, "A").resize(ubound(arr, 1), ubound(arr, 2)) = arr

end with
```

Comment: Wow, what a great example., thanks. A follow up question, what it sheet A already contains other values? For example, our dictionary from Sheet B might contain 'country' and 'animal', but Sheet A also contains a 'Food' column, in between. How would you combat this?

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain what's happening there?

Comment: Instead of only collecting the IDs, it collects all IDs and the values from the next three columns. It only updates the values in the next three columns where ID is in the dictionary.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Probably the best, easily verifiable answer I've seen on here for a long time.